# VirtualBox mounted with Vagrant reach maximum diskspace

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

Today my Windows build machine reached its disk space limit. It turned out that I had more than 400GB in the folder

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\VirtualBox VMs
```

During the build process, a virtual machine is mounted using Vagrant and VirtualBox. The previous virtual machine is normally destroyed beforehand.

Does anyone know how I could change my Virtualbox or Vagrant configuration to avoid that happening again?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to fix the issue but for the time being you can remove the VMs manually via the Virtualbox GUI.